# AngularJS Quiz app

Tags: angularjs, html

I have two score fields. One is at the right and the second is in the last "finish" page. The first one is working properly , but when I go to the finish page the finish score doesn't count the last click on the last question.

Here is the plunkr for the whole app: http://plnkr.co/edit/wTQHOz

```
 $scope.answerClick = function(index){
    $scope.clicks++;

    if($scope.clicks === 4){
        resultService.score = $scope.score;
        $location.path('/finish');
    }

    if(index === $scope.currentQ.answer){
        $scope.score++;
    }
    $scope.move(+1);


};
```

Comment: Open the browser's error console. Fix all errors it shows. Don't ask us to recreate the entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with Angular, it's a logical mistake. The reason your result doesn't count the last question is because code's sequence is wrong. (  I answered your last question but didn't find this bug either..)

```
if(index === $scope.currentQ.answer){
    $scope.score++;
}

if($scope.clicks === 4){
    resultService.score = $scope.score;
    $location.path('/finish');
}
```

You should validate current question's answer at first then check whether it's the last one.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I knew it would be obvious mistake